# Suppose $A_1, A_2$ are affine subsets of $V$, then $A_1\cap A_2$ is either an affine subset of $V$ or $\emptyset$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

**The Problem**: Suppose $A_1, A_2$ are affine subsets of $V$, then $A_1\cap A_2$ is either an affine subset of $V$ or $\emptyset$.

**The Source**: Sheldon Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* 3rd edition.

**My Background**: Sheldon Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* 3rd edition Section 1.A-Section 3.E.

**My Attempt**: Suppose $A_1=\vec{v}+V_1$, $A_2=\vec{w}+V_2$, where $V_1, V_2$ are subspaces of $V$.After trying a few options, I conjectured that if $A_1\cap A_2\neq\emptyset$, then $A_1\cap A_2=\frac{\vec{v}+\vec{w}}{2}+(V_1+V_2)$, where $V_1+V_2$ is the sum of $V_1$ and $V_2$.

Proving $A_1\cap A_2\subseteq\frac{\vec{v}+\vec{w}}{2}+(V_1+V_2)$ turns out to be quite straightforward; but I failed to show that $\frac{\vec{v}+\vec{w}}{2}+(V_1+V_2)\subseteq A_1\cap A_2$. Is my conjecture false? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simpler than this! You don't have to consider subspaces! There are two cases

i)$A_{1}\bigcap\,A_{2}\neq\varnothing $ or

ii)$\,\,A_{1}\bigcap\,A_{2}=\varnothing$.

In case i) take $v,w \in A_{1}\bigcap\,A_{2}$. Then $v,w \in A_{1}$ which gives $\lambda v+(1-\lambda)w \in A_{1}$ where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.But $v,w \in A_{2}$, hence $\lambda\,v+(1-\lambda)w\,\in\,A_{2}$.

Therefore for any $ v,w \in A_{1}\bigcap\,A_{2}$ we get $\lambda\,v+(1-\lambda)w\, \in A_{1}\bigcap\,A_{2}$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$

which is the definition of an affine space! This is all we need!

Comment: It seems to me this is the definition of a convex space, not an affine space.  You've proved the intersection must be convex, but not all convex spaces are affine.

Comment: @RobertShore The proof works for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, not just for $\lambda \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: Exactly! $\lambda$ is free in $\mathbb{R}$